# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting Android apps
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1602).

Comment: Is there a deadline for the ads?

Comment: @Flow December 2014 is the deadline, essentially.

Answer (score 12):

[image: MAXS - Receive notifications and control your Android device over XMPP]

Comment: I am the author of MAXS, which is 100% open source and ad-free.

Comment: Now **this** is interesting. Based on the "not implemented yet" messages, it looks like you've already considered most of the obvious feature requests (File operations, `sms show [contact]`, etc). I'm watching this one like a hawk for sure.

Comment: Thank you. :-) Most commands are fully functional. IIRC file operations. If there are some missing you'd like to see, simply post a feature request at http://projectmaxs.org/forums

Comment: Is there any plan for WhatsApp integration?

Comment: No, I wont put any effort into supporting proprietary systems. But I wouldn't reject third party contributions for such systems.

Answer (score 10):

[image: yaxim - yet another XMPP Instant Messenger for Android]

Comment: The yaxim XMPP client is a community effort, I am maintaining it and am open for comments/feedback.

Answer (score 9):

[image: AnkiDroid: Memorize everything!]

Comment: yeah, AnkiDroid. Thanks Nicolas for this fine app :)

Comment: You should maybe consider changing the grey text on white background. It's nearly invisible.

Comment: @Flow: Thanks for the tip! I will try to make it a bit darker.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Car Dashboard - Car Home Application]

Comment: Full disclosure: I am the developer of this application. The link is to my free version of the app, although I do make some money off sales of the Pro version. Thanks for your consideration of promoting my app :)

Comment: A quick bit of slightly OT marketing advice: it's worth including the word "free" in the banner. That one word really grabs people's attention.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Showr web & RSS image widgets FREE on Google Play]

Comment: This is my commercial app, but it's a free download (supported by a "pro" upgrade). There are *several* questions on the site asking for apps like this, so I hope the community will find it a helpful and relevant suggestion. Your support will enable me to keep contributing to the site!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Izzy's Android-Handbuch (Deutsch/German)]

Comment: Just a note to others, this is a book that Izzy has written

Comment: Ah, thanks @BryanDenny! I know, "full disclosure", but thought the format of the post is fixed. My, I could have thought of using the comments myself #D Yes, fully correct: I wrote this book, and as the cover states: it's available free, licensed CC-BY-NC-SA, there are two more available behind the link (also German), and if anyone wants to say "thanks", follow the Amazon links on my server to start your shopping tour :)

Comment: This is encrypted, and I don't have the password!

Comment: Nothing is encrypted there. All content of the referred server is open and free to everybody. Feel free to drop into chat if you have problems, I'll gladly help you out!

Comment: @Izzy - Is there an English version planned?

Comment: @Izzy - Yeah, I was joking. It's no use in German...

Comment: @Compro01 No, unfortunately not. It's already eating most of my time to keep it up-to-date in one language. To give you a pointer: the book started in early 2011, and the latest version has already passed number 50. There are 3 different versions to be maintained as well: the free CC-BY-NC-SA linked here, a payed version for Amazon Kindle (count it as "donation version" to encourage me to continue, as well as to cover server costs), and the print version by Franzis...

Comment: @Poldie Thanks for clarification! OK, I got the joke (we have a similar one for one of our politicians, were it's said NSA couldn't crack his phone's encryption, and that also played as his "dialect" :) But good you "solved the mystery": other readers might have been misled otherwise...

Answer (score 6):

[image: Find apps by real-life categories!]

Comment: As this question is expressively off-topic on Android.SE, I've created a site specifically for that: app listings by real-life categories. Not only can you compare "similar" apps in rating, votes, linked reviews, count of permissions and concerns – you can even search for them based on category and permissions it should (or should not) have. So I think that's something we could point people to from here. For a quick-glance what it is, there's even a little [online help](http://android.izzysoft.de/help.php) pointing out "hidden gems" and more. Hope you like it!

Comment: Apart from what I've mentioned in my previous comment, yesterday the new "article section" went live. Hopefully it will collect a lot of useful information soon (often referring *here*, as you can see in its first "regular" post: [Android Markets: How safe are alternative sources?](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android_markets_safe_to_use)).

Answer (score 5):

[image: Want to RANDOMLY generate a LIST of integers? The answer is RANDOMLYST]

Comment: I am the developer of this app. Randomlyst is completely free and without ads or in-app purchases.

Comment: I am curious what the use case for such an app would be?

Comment: Some people requires a list of random generated numbers for selecting random rows of a text file, to pick randomly items of a sorted collection, to simulate the results of throwing a coin or rolling a die, or simply for statistics. This app lets the user to generate, sort, shuffle, save to SD Card, or share with other users the lists of integer numbers they generate. I'm working in additional features but I can't disclose them now because they are still in design phase.

Answer (score 0):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Answer (score -1):

[image: robotics stack exchange]